# Java opengl block based game performance

Tags: java, performance, opengl, lwjgl

I'm using lwjgl with Java to build a block based 3d game, something like Minecraft. I'm currently have a Block class which contains the functions void Update() and void Draw() and I call them in the order Update() and Draw() each cycle of the game loop. The function draw contains a texture.bind() at the begging to apply texture on the block and then have 6 if conditions to check if needed to render 6 sides respectively.
Example:

```
if(rendertop)
GL11.glVertex3f(position.x, position.y, position.z);
.....
```

At the moment it works pretty well except when I draw a lot of those blocks it slow down the fps so the game is unplayable. After some searching on google I found out that there are better ways to draw 3d objects to the screen other then send to the graphics card each vertex again and again in each draw. I tried to use lists but it only seems to take a lot more memory. I made a new list for each side of the block and called it if the side needed to be rendered same as the example above, which means each block have 6 lists.
This is how I made the lists:

```
GL11.glNewList(displayListId, GL11.GL_COMPILE);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
...... (Calling GL11.glVertex3f to draw the side)
GL11.glEnd();
GL11.glEndList();
```

And I called it like this:

```
if(rendertop)
GL11.glCallList(displayListId);
```

But as I said before it only made the game very slow, I know this is probably have something to do with the way I implemented it.
Another problem in using that method is then you destroy the block you need to delete the displaylist and I don't know how to do that.

Anyone can suggest a way to increase the performance using the displaylists or other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [vertex arrays](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Arrays) or [vertex buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object) to batch your rendering up.

Each VA or VBO should contain (for example) a 16x16x16 block of cubes.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have display lists implemented in your code, you probably won't notice a significant speed increase with putting each block alone in its own Vertex buffer.

Do what genpfault said, but also I would highly advise using an octree, quad-tree, or some other kind of tree to decide whether certain blocks are visible ([hidden surface determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_frustum_culling)). With this you will notice a large performance increase.